# Apply a lambda function while appending to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, lambda

Imagine a one dimensional array 'inter' and an empty list 'visual_pred'. I want to iterate over all elements in the array and append each element to my list while adding the element with the list's last entry.


My code looks like this:

```
visual = []

for x in inter:
    if x > 0:
        visual.append(lambda x: x + visual[-1])
    else:
        visual.append(visual[-1])
```

After executing the code all entries in my list 'inter' looks like this:

```
function __main__.lambda(x)
```

What is the problem here and how can I challenge it?

Comment: `visual.append(x + visual[-1])`,

Comment: Why do you use a ``lambda`` at all? The ``lambda`` syntax serves to create functions, and you appear not to want one.

Comment: you are storing the reference of *lambda expression*. I don't think you need lambda here

Comment: Sorry! Blockhead me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is appending the lambda function itself to your list and not the lambda functions output. I don't actually see why you need a lambda here anyway. This does what you want.

```
visual = []

for x in inter:
    if x > 0:
        visual.append(x + visual[-1])
    else:
        visual.append(visual[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As `BeanBagTheCat` pointed out, you're appending the lambda function itself to your list and not the lambda functions output. You can write the same code by `BeanBagTheCat` in one line using list-comprehension as follows:

`visual = [x + visual[-1] if x > 0 else visual[-1] for x in inter]`